# json to php code , need function improvement

Tags: php, javascript

My site has lot of javascript, our frontend designer embedded settings code as json format, in js files . I need to this settings json value, from php server . and there are some dynamic changes. I coverted this settings json value into php array .. there are lot of them . so I written a function to convert into php code format

I have written a function `toPhp`, which is posted in http://jsfiddle.net/2HKMU/

I tried to convert one js file settings into php code .. which works ..

```
var config_topfive = {
    "type":"topfive", 
    "options":{ 
        "ascending":false, "percentage":true, "limits":[25,5] 
    }
};

console.log( toPhp( config_topfive ) );
```

which prints

```
array(
    "type" => "topfive", 
    "options" =>  array(
        "ascending" => false, 
        "percentage" => true, 
        "limits" => array(25,5)
    )
)
```

I would like to know, I miss anything on this conversion .. how could I improve this function more better ..

I know `json_decode` , but I would like to keep this `setting json value in js file ,which made by designer`  in to php config file .. eg : `config_topfive.php` . I will copy paste console print of this function `console.log( toPhp( config_topfive ) )` into php file

so final my php code in `config_topfive.php` look like

```
<?php

return array(
    "type" => "topfive", 
    "options" =>  array(
        "ascending" => false, 
        "percentage" => true, 
        "limits" => array(25,5)
    )
);
```

Comment: why not just json_decode() his strings as it returns an array of whatever is in the json anyway oO

Comment: As long as you're using PHP 5.2+ json_decode should do all this for you.

Comment: you need to convert js json to php array then why not use php json_decode()... am I interpreting something wrong .... ?

Comment: setting code in json formatt .. that in js files .. I will copy paste this `console.log` of  `toPhp` function into php config file.

Comment: @dreamCoder updated question .. please suggest !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you didn't use  `json_decode` and `json_encode`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

sample  `json_decode`

```
 $json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
 print_r(json_decode($json));
```

sample `json_encode`

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

 echo json_encode($arr);
```

output

```
 {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

edit:

i wrote this test it

```
function MakeArray(Json){
  this.JArray=Json;
  this.PArray=function(ar){
      for (var J in ar) {
            var Type=typeof(ar[J])
            if(Type=="string"){
                ar[J]="\""+ar[J]+"\"";
            }else if( Type== "object") {
                if(ar[J] instanceof Array){
                   ar[J]=this.PArray(ar[J]);
                   //ar[J]="\""+J+"\"=>array("+ar[J].join(',')+")";
                   ar[J]="array("+ar[J].join(',')+")";
                }else{
                   ar[J]="\""+J+"\"=>array("+this.MArray(ar[J])+")";
                }
                //ar[J]=this.MArray(ar[J]);       
            }
      }
      return ar;
  }
  this.MArray=function(IArray){
      var Output=Array();
      var Count=0;
      for (var i in IArray) {
          var Type=typeof(IArray[i]);
          if( Type== "object") {
              if(IArray[i] instanceof Array){
                  IArray[i]=this.PArray(IArray[i]);
                  Out="\""+i+"\"=>array("+IArray[i].join(',')+")";
              }else{
                  Out="\""+i+"\"=>array("+this.MArray(IArray[i])+")";
              }
          }else{
              if(Type=="string" || typeof(i)=="string"){
                  Out="\""+i+"\"=>\""+IArray[i]+"\"";
              }else if(Type=="number"){
                  Out=IArray[i];
              }else{
                  Out="\""+i+"\"=>"+IArray[i]; 
              }

          }
          Output[Count++]=Out;
      }
      return Output.join(',');

  }
  return "array("+this.MArray(this.JArray)+")";

}
document.getElementById('php').innerHTML =MakeArray(config_topfive);
```

Comment: no... that's not I mean . I would like to keep `setting json value in js file ,which made by designer` in php config file .. eg : config_topfive.php . I will copy paste this function console output into php file

Comment: if i understand you want first read `json` from `js` then `decode` it and dump it as array in `config`.and you want  `encode` array config as `json` and write into `js` too

Comment: I wrote a Function for this test it

Comment: your not correct always try `var config_topfive = {"series":{"a":[1,12],"b":8,"c":[3,444]}};` . output should be `array("series" => array("a" => array(1,12), "b" => 8, "c" => array(3,444)))` . check code http://jsfiddle.net/2HKMU/2/ with your http://jsfiddle.net/qp5Am/ .

Comment: bug for `var config_topfive = {"series":{"a":[1,12],"b":[5,"dg"],"v":"fhfgh","c":[3,444]}};` solved

Comment: bug for `var config_topfive = {"series":{"a":[1,12],"b":[5,"dg",[3,[456,456],4]],"v":"fhfgh","c":[3,444]}};` solved

Answer (score 1):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) would allow you to achieve the same result and allows you to pass an 'associative' bool to determine whether you want it as a normal array or associative.

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) would allow you to perform the opposite.